# Css isn't making changes to my HTML webpage although they are linked correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I edit anything in CSS, it doesn't make any difference to my HTML file and therefore doesn't display a change in chrome. It was working earlier just fine until I restarted my computer (although I doubt that had anything to do with it). No matter what changes I make, they are not displayed on the webpage but the changes I made in CSS previously are still displayed.

My HTML script:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//bootstrap.cdn.url.wow.css">
                <style>
        a {
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
                </style>
            <link href="style.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>

    <title>Webpage practice</title>
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <u><h1>My page</h1></u>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home_page.html">Home page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">col1</div>
                <div class="col">col2</div>
                <div class="col">col3</div>

                <em><footer>@2020 My Site</footer></em>
    </body>

</html>
```

My css script:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: #999;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 5px
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline; 
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 09px;
    display: inline; 

}

nav ul li {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px

}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
}

.row {
    background: #3498DB
}

.col {
    color: white;
    font: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: extra-expanded;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding:05px;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    background:#999;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
}
```

I am also using bootsrapCDN which could also be the culprit as my script stopped displaying shortly after I added it.

I have just added Jquery as it was displaying an error in the console to add it. Not it displays the error messagge: "bootstrap.cdn.url.wow.css/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache and checked the browser's console for errors? Also, does your browser have any extensions/addons/plugins enabled? Finally, have you tested this in different browsers?

Comment: It appears there is one error and it reads as follows: util.js:179 Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at Object.jQueryDetection (util.js:179)
    at util.js:195
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
jQueryDetection @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: Well, did you include jQuery and include it before Bootstrap.js?

Comment: Yes I just did and now it says "bootstrap.cdn.url.wow.css/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: I don't see any such file in your code with the name bootstrap.cdn.url.wow.css

Comment: Yes because I don't see where I get this file from

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with CDN stylesheets a safe and reliable option for overriding their rules with your own is to use `!important`.

Also there is a better alternative to this
Just make sure your rules come after bootstrap's rules and you'll be fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//bootstrap.cdn.url.wow.css">
<style>
  a {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: So where do I put this code? and is the "text-decoration" part necessary? Also, where do I put the "!important"?

Comment: Hexxx's code goes between <head> and </head> in the HTML — which is where you already have it. 

The point they're making is that you put the .css file BEFORE your internal CSS. "text-decoration" is there because you put it there. All it does is underline text. If you don't want your text underlined, remove it.